# Can anyone provide me some links to start Adobe AIR for android

Tags: android, air

I am new to Adobe AIR. I don't know the S/W requirements to start development in android. Can anyone suggest me good and easy tutorial links to start Adobe AIR for Android. And also some good tutorial for code and example.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the tutorials for Adobe AIR for Android

[Developing and using Adobe AIR native extensions for Android devices](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html)

[mobile tutors for adobe air](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/build-a-gps-speedometer-getting-into-air-for-android/)

[building an app using adobe air](http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/build-an-android-app-using-adobe-air/)

[video tutorial for Android adobe air](http://www.leebrimelow.com/new-video-tutorial-on-air-for-android-part-1/)